# VBA looping - using values from a column

Tags: vba, loops, excel, finance

Sub Combined()

```
Dim stockcode As String
Dim marketcode As String
stockcode = Sheets("NYSE screener").Range("B1").Value
marketcode = Sheets("Stock input").Range("B2").Value

Sheets.Add.Name = stockcode & "BS"

With Worksheets(stockcode & "BS").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Financials?s=" & stockcode & ":" & marketcode & "&subview=BalanceSheet", Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1"))
    '.Name = "67083361_zpid"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Worksheets(stockcode & "BS").Range("A115:F153").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets(stockcode & "BS").Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Worksheets(stockcode & "BS").Rows("40:170").Clear



Sheets.Add.Name = stockcode & "CF"

With Worksheets(stockcode & "CF").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Financials?s=" & stockcode & ":" & marketcode & "&subview=CashFlow", Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1"))
    '.Name = "67083361_zpid"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Worksheets(stockcode & "CF").Range("A115:F142").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets(stockcode & "CF").Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Worksheets(stockcode & "CF").Rows("29:159").Clear


Sheets.Add.Name = stockcode & "IS"

With Worksheets(stockcode & "IS").QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "URL;http://markets.ft.com/research/Markets/Tearsheets/Financials?s=" & stockcode & ":" & marketcode & "&subview=IncomeStatement", Destination:=Range( _
    "$A$1"))
    '.Name = "67083361_zpid"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
    .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
    .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
    .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
    .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
    .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
    .WebDisableRedirections = False
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

Worksheets(stockcode & "IS").Range("A115:F161").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets(stockcode & "IS").Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Worksheets(stockcode & "IS").Rows("48:178").Clear
```

End Sub

'I have a column of stock codes in another worksheet called NYSE screener. I would like to use the values and run the whole code to obtain three individual worksheets. How do i create the loop? The values are in column B of NYSE screener

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what sort of answer you're looking for, but for accessing an external workbook:

```
Dim wbk as Workbook
Set wbk = Workbooks(<filepath>)
```

then you just have to reference like you regularly would in VBA

```
wbk.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
```

The syntax for the for loop could be something like:

```
For i in wbk.worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B1000")

Next i
```

I would suggest reading the list of stock codes into an array as the first thing you do in your code (use RDim so it can be dynamically resized if you're not sure how many stock codes you have). Then you can loop through the array in each of the separate sheets without having to access the file again each time.

I'm writing that from memory so you may have to tweak the syntax slightly.

Comment: Hi Isaac, so i have to define the stock list as an array first and then define i so it does the whole macro for each entry in the stock list? How do i define where to search the array for?